Definition of divisor on Algebraic (Deligne-Mumford) Stacks
In Theorem 5.2 in the paper "the irreducibility of the space of curves of given genus" by Deligne-Mumford (http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1969__36__75_0.pdf), they have used the term divisor with normal crossing on a stack. But I couldn't find a definition in the paper. As far as I understand, in the proper, they picked an arbitrary etale map from a scheme to the stack, under which the pullback of the divisor to the scheme is divisor with simple normal crossing.
In "Stacks and Moduli (2024)" by Jarod Alper (https://sites.math.washington.edu/~jarod/moduli.pdf), the definition of a divisor on a Deligne-Mumford stack is given to be

My question is shouldn't a divisor on Deligne-Mumford stack be a closed substack such that the pullback is a divisor with respect to all etale presentations. Or are they equivalent?
